# Cursor: Maximum integer value remains in rows and other values becomes zero in previous rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as follows:

myTable t1

```
 ID   RENT
 ----------
 10   2000
 10   5000
 10   7000
 10   1000
 10    500
```

and I want to update all values on RENT with '0' integer value except the maximum rent value stays i-e '7000' So my table would de like the following:

```
 ID   RENT
 ----------
 10      0
 10      0
 10   7000
 10      0
 10      0
```

Please can anyone help me with this, I was told to do it with cursor

Comment: I hope you are storing rent as a number, not a string.  Don't use single quote for number values.

Comment: "I was told to do it with cursor" for what reason? Is this a homework task learning about cursors? Or some other reason?

Comment: Start by reading the documentation on cursors - it has examples. Or just search the internet for examples. But TRY something. One hint - select your rows and order by rent descending and simply skip the first row. Another hint - select all rows that are less than the maximum.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions and an updatable CTE:

```
with toudpate as (
      select t.*, max(rent) over (partition by id) as max_rent
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set rent = 0
    where rent < max_rent;
```